# Problems with receiving strings via UART0 on Arduino UNO

Tags: c, string, avr, uart, serial-communication

I'm trying to write my own library for sending messages from my Arduino UNO via UART0 to my computer.

The library works successfully except the part where I want to receive strings. The code of the library is:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000

#define EVEN_P 0
#define ODD_P 1

#define BAUD_RATE 57600

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// Initialize UART0 communication
void UART0_Init_Custom(unsigned long BaudRate, char AsyncDoubleSpeed, char DataSizeInBits, char ParityEVENorODD, char StopBits)
{
    uint16_t UBBR_Value = lrint (F_CPU / 16 / BaudRate - 1 ); // maybe 16L??

    // Setting the U2X bit to 1 for double speed asynchronous (default = 0, normal speed)
    if (AsyncDoubleSpeed == 1) UCSR0A = (1 << U2X0);

    // Upper part of the baud number (bits 8 to 11)
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(UBBR_Value >> 8);
    // Rest of the baud number
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)(UBBR_Value);

    // Enable the receiver and transmitter
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);

    // Set 2 stop bits (default = 1)
    if (StopBits == 2) UCSR0C = (1 << USBS0);

    // Set parity
    if (ParityEVENorODD == EVEN_P) UCSR0C |= (1 << UPM01);
    if (ParityEVENorODD == ODD_P) UCSR0C |= (3 << UPM00);

    // Set data length (default = 5 bits)
    if (DataSizeInBits == 6) UCSR0C |= (1 << UCSZ00); // 6-bit
    if (DataSizeInBits == 7) UCSR0C |= (2 << UCSZ00); // 7-bit
    if (DataSizeInBits == 8) UCSR0C |= (3 << UCSZ00); // 8-bit
    if (DataSizeInBits == 9) UCSR0C |= (7 << UCSZ00); // 9-bit
}

void UART0_Init(unsigned long BaudRate)
{
    if (BaudRate == 115200)
    {
        UART0_Init_Custom((BaudRate/2),1,8,0,2);
    }
    else
    {
        UART0_Init_Custom(BaudRate,0,8,0,2);
    }
}

// Receive Data UART0
char UART0_GET(void)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)));
    return UDR0;
}

// Transmit Data UART0
void UART0_PUT(char data)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

// Transmit Data-String UART0
void UART0_PRINT(char* String)
{
    while(*String)
    {
        UART0_PUT(*String++);
    }   
}

// Receive Data-String UART0
char* UART0_READ(void)
{
    char* ReceivedString;
    char ReceivedBit;
    int StringBit = 0;
    memset(&ReceivedString,0,sizeof(ReceivedString));
    while ((ReceivedBit=UART0_GET())!=13)
    {
        UART0_PUT(ReceivedBit);
        ReceivedString[StringBit] = ReceivedBit;
        StringBit++;
    }
    ReceivedString[StringBit] = 13;
    ReceivedString[StringBit++] = 10;
    UART0_PUT(10);
    strncpy(ReceivedString, ReceivedString, StringBit+1);
    return(ReceivedString);
}

char* Input;
int main(void)
{
    UART0_Init(BAUD_RATE);
    UART0_PRINT((char*)"Give a message and I will return it\r\n");
    while(1)
    {   
        Input = UART0_READ();
        UART0_PRINT((char*)"The message was:");
        UART0_PRINT(Input);
    }
}
```

When running this code, PuTTY shows some random tokens and stops. I cannot insert anything anymore.

Comment: "PuTTY shows some random tokens and stops" - which random tokens? Are you able to give us the output?

Comment: Also, try to narrow down your problem if possible, giving a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), perhaps through the **Divide and conquer** method which that help page suggests.

Comment: "PuTTY shows some random tokens and stops" - sounds like wrong baud rate settings

Comment: `char* ReceivedString;` is not been initialised, it does not point to any memory for the string. Also beware that a local string will go out of life when you exit the function.

Comment: And, in `memset(&ReceivedString,0,sizeof(ReceivedString));` that is the size of the pointer. There is no definition anywhere of what size the string is (should be). In any case `&ReceivedString` is wrong too, it should be `ReceivedString` without the `&`.

Comment: After you get the initialization issues settled, be aware that when you are making a `C` string that it needs a zero at the end to terminate it.  I'm pretty sure the `strncpy(ReceivedString, ReceivedString, StringBit+1);` won't do it for you

Comment: So, do you use the Arduino framework or is that supposed to be plain C (not C++)?

Comment: What's wrong with Serial? You can set databitsize, stopbits and parity there, if you need.

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison I was not allowed to post a picture of the output in PuTTY because I don't have enough points yet on stackoverflow yet. 
And what is your advice to narrow it down? I thought this was the minimal amount of code you needed.

Comment: @Gravell it was not the wrong baud rate, because `UART0_PRINT` worked fine, but after `UART0_READ` it stopped and started doing weird stuff.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, I will try to apply your feedback asap

Comment: @Olaf It is supposed to be plain C.

Comment: @TheCoffeeRanger: The it is better to use the AVR tag, not Arduino. Latter implies Arduino framework/context, which is not C.

Comment: Note: guards like `#ifndef UART_R
#define UART_R
` are unnecessary in implementation files, as you don't `#include` them in other files. And where is the header for that library? You should include it in the implementation, too to ensure the prototypes match the implementation.

Comment: "I was not allowed to post a picture of the output in PuTTY because" - You are not allowed to edit your question and post the text? In case you tried posting an image of text: That is against site-rules anyway! Post text as text!

Comment: @Olaf, thnks for your feedback.
I will take into account next time.

Futhermore I could not copy the text from PuTTY, because it was forzen and could not reproduce the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue you have is that you have not allocated any buffer in which to store the received data (as pointed out in the comments by @WeatherVane).

When writing a function in C that is going to return a string, you have two choices: either the caller provides a buffer and passes a pointer to it into the function, or the function allocates the buffer and returns a pointer to it.

If the function is going to allocate it, then it will have to allocate it on the heap, using the `malloc` function. You could not use a local variable inside the function, because if you did then as soon as you exited the function, the variable is out of scope. In theory you could use a static variable as a buffer, but if you did that you could only read one string at a time.

If the caller is going to provide a buffer then it could use a local variable, a static variable, or allocate from the heap.

When the buffer is allocated on the heap, no matter who allocates it, the caller must free it when it is finished with it, using the `free` function.

Embedded systems generally minimize the use of heap allocated variables - see [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-using-malloc-and-free-a-really-bad-idea-on-arduino) for some info about the reasons for that - so you might be better to allow the caller to allocate the buffer, like this:

```
void UART0_READ(char* buffer, int buflen)
{
//  ... here goes code to read into buffer
}

#define BUFSIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    char input[BUFSIZE];
    UART0_READ(input, BUFSIZE);
    ...
}
```

Note that I defined the `UART0_READ` function to take two arguments: the address of the buffer, and it's length. Another thing your program is missing is any guard against the buffer overflowing.

Inside your input routine, use the buflen argument in eg. the call to memset, and inside the loop that reads characters to exit early if too many characters are read.

The buffer is defined as a local character array in the calling function.

Some other notes:

- Don't forget to add a zero, one past the last character added to the array. This also means that you must exit the loop after reading buflen-1 characters, so you have enough space for the 0.
- I'm not sure why you are calling `strncpy` ? You seem to be copying the string onto itself.
- Running a program with stray pointers in a full size OS will often result in a segfault. Embedded environments often lack the sophistication to detect  incorrect memory accesses so instead you might get less predictable behaivour (such as random garbage coming out the serial port).

Comment: Nice answer, covered the short-comings well.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I have time I will try to apply your feedback.

I used to `memset` to fill `ReceivedString` with zeros.
Then import all characters from the input, but `ReceivedString` should be full with zeros due to the `memset` function. Therefore I copied it onto itself removing the remaining zeros with `strncpy`.